# Algebra and summation question

Tags: algebra-precalculus

${(1+\frac{q_jr^i}{1-q_j})}^{-1}=\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} (-1)^{k-1}(\frac{q_jr^i}{1-q_j})^{k-1}$

What rule is being used to go from the LHS to the RHS? My knowledge in maths is first year undergrad, but I'm not sure if a more advanced concept is being used here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Observe that for $|x|<1$

$$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}x^n=\frac{1}{1-x}\tag{Sum of infinite GP}$$

Substitute $n+1=k$ to get,

$$\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}x^{k-1}=\frac{1}{1-x}$$

Now, replace $x$ with $-\dfrac{q_jr^i}{1-q_j}$ to get the required answer.

In the end, ensure that $\left|\dfrac{q_jr^i}{1-q_j}\right|<1$